# is it possible for current_user to be initializer, in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to use something like `current_user` or `User.current` in the initializers? I've tried something like

```
Something = Something::Some.new configure do |something|

    something.somethingelse = current_user.key

end
```

but it states it can't find the `key` but I know that `key` is a column in User table. I can do `something = current_user.key` or `something = User.key` in under model or controller and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` is usually set in the `application_controller` of your application. If you use a gem like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to handle user authentications for example, they take care of setting such method for you.

The initializers' code is executed when you launch your application on your server (local machine or remote server), therefor you understand that a "current_user" (understand a "logged in" user) simply does not exists (yet).