# Call helper function from rails 4 notifications subscribe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I need to save all controller notification to database. I create a /config/initializers/notifications.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe('process_action.action_controller') do |name, start, finish, id, payload|
  Action.create(
    action_type: name,
    user: current_user,
    data: payload
  )
end
```

but I get error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for main:Object
```

`current_user` is a helper it app/helpers/session_helper.rb and it works in entire application.

I need to know user, which made action. How can I call `current_user` in this context?

Answer (score 0):

> current_user is usually set in the application_controller of your
>   application. If you use a gem like Devise to handle user
>   authentications for example, they take care of setting such method for
>   you.
>
> The initializers' code is executed when you launch your application on
>   your server (local machine or remote server), therefor you understand
>   that a "current_user" (understand a "logged in" user) simply does not
>   exists (yet).

Source - [is it possible for current_user to be initializer, in rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237425/is-it-possible-for-current-user-to-be-initializer-in-rails-3)

Hope this helps!

Comment: O! really, I define `current_user` in `ApplicationController`

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  include SessionsHelper
  ...`

Answer (score 0):

> current_user is a helper it app/helpers/session_helper.rb and it works in entire application.

**Let me correct you here.**

You can't access `current_user` in your initializer files. Initializers are run once on application startup, so don't expect accessing `current_user` like this.

Comment: sorry, I overlooked that include current_user in ApplicationController

Answer (score 0):

I found solution: [append_info_to_payload](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionController/Instrumentation/append_info_to_payload)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def append_info_to_payload(payload)
    super
    payload[:current_user] = current_user
  end
```

From this answer:
[How to add attribute to existing Notifications payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633361/how-to-add-attribute-to-existing-notifications-payload)

Comment: It will throw error when you will start the application server I guess!